# How to combine two table's but no data replication

Tags: mysql

Here i have used two table in this two tables trip id was common
    1. combine two tables based on trip_id in where condition using trip_flight_id.
    Below i have Explained the table details

```
 table: details

       trip_flight_id   trip_id(f.k)
       2178              2054
       2179              2054

    table: booking_details

    booking_id trip_id
    1           2054
    2           2054

    I need a result based on trip_flight_id

    if(trip_flight_id=2178)
    booking_id   trip_id   trip_flight_id
     1            2054      2178

    if(trip_flight_id=2179)
     booking_id trip_id    trip_flight_id
       1           2054     2179

I tried the below query but not shows the exact result

SELECT * FROM 
`details` tbd inner join 
`booking_details` tfd on tfd.trip_id=tbd.trip_id 
where tfd.trip_flight_id=2179
```

please help me

Comment: one change if(trip_flight_id=2179) Booking_id was 2 not 1

Comment: what about if 3rd row is 2180, 2054?

Comment: yes but booking id is 3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are trying to achieve is not possible with your current schema. You should use `booking_id` as foreign key in `details` table instead of `trip_id`, this way when you use this query

```
SELECT b.booking_id, b.trip_id, a.trip_flight_id
FROM
    details a 
    INNER JOIN booking_details b ON a.booking_id = b.booking_id
WHERE
    a.trip_flight_id= 2179
```

you get this result

```
+------------+---------+----------------+
| booking_id | trip_id | trip_flight_id |
+------------+---------+----------------+
|          2 |    2054 |           2179 |
+------------+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```